# How to setup multilingual text to speech API for text with mixed-language inputs?

Tags: python-3.x, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech, pyttsx, gtts

i was trying gtts this way :

```
from gtts import gTTS
mytext = 'Welcome to gtts আজ একটি ভাল দিন'
language = 'en'
myobj = gTTS(text=mytext, lang=language, slow=False)
myobj.save("welcome.mp3")
```

you can see the text i am working with can contain multiple language inputs(typically two) in a particular sentence,gtts doesn't work well in such situation, specially when arabic is mixed with bengali in a sentence, which free multilingual tts api to use in such situation?can we setup gtts such a way that it can deal well with mixed language input well like tesseract ocr engine can take multiple language input for doing ocr on mixed language input?